# What could account for different behavior over ssh vs local

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I am encountering some very strange behavior when working over ssh vs locally (using Raspbian Jessie). I have a development machine (at 10.1.0.53) from which I'm sending udp packets to the Pi at one second intervals. Now, if I execute the following command (same user):

```
sudo tcpdump ip and udp and host 10.1.0.53
```

I get correct behavior locally, but unpredictable behavior over ssh. Namely, tcpdump will miss some of the packets, some of the time. Worse, sometimes it doesn't exhibit buggy behavior via ssh, and sometimes it does, so I'm unsure exactly how to reproduce this bug. I am logged in as the same user, and issue the exact same command in both cases. In both cases the interface is `eth0`, the on-board ethernet adapter. I feel like I'm missing something stupid.

So, I guess the most fundamental, answerable question is: what might account for the same command executing differently over ssh vs locally? I am clearly missing something.